# Safari 6.0 issue that pushes CSS positioning to the left

Tags: css

Ok, it's an issue I'm having but trying my best to make it sound not so localized as this could actually be something to do with Safari...

On my website at http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/101d/html_new/index.html we have a button styled as ozo_button with an inside span of btn_arrow_right which looks in it's correct form in all browsers apart from Safari like this:

[image]

What is causing the CSS to make the button look like this (below) in Safari 6.0 where the arrow is behind the text?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a class="ozo_button" href="https://console.101distribution.com?v=register" style="width:200px;cursor:pointer;"><span class="btn_arrow_right ozo_button_icon">icon</span><span class="ozo_button_label">Sign-Up &amp; Get Started</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.ozo_button {
font-family: Verdana;
font-weight: bold;
font-size:13px;
width:75px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
padding:5px 15px 5px 0px;
border:1px solid #999999;
text-align:center;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
color:#333;
border:1px solid #DDD;
background:#FFFFFF;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#EEE));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 90% 90deg, #EEE, #FFF);  
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a.ozo_button span.ozo_button_icon {
vertical-align:middle;
margin-left: 0px;
float: left;
}
a.ozo_button span.ozo_button_label{
vertical-align:middle;
padding-left:25px;
}
.btn_arrow_right{
text-indent:-9999px;
position:absolute;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background:url(../images/arena_sprite.png) -263px -80px no-repeat transparent;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, but you also have `.btn_arrow_right` that is contributing style rules in the mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` based on requirement also use `float:left;` if you are using `display:block;`